# BASH/SH/ .. AutoConf: Wrapping string comparison

Tags: shell, autoconf, m4

I am modifying a configure.ac for use with AutoConf: http://mathpad.wikidot.com/acousto-configure-ac

The script points out that it needs to run on darwin, solaris, cygwin and linux.

I assume this is why it uses an arcane method of comparing strings:

```
foo="1"
if test "x$foo" != "x0"; then
```

This double negative makes it difficult to read through the code. Can I clean it up?

How might I implement a string comparison macro:

```
if STR_EQUAL( $foo, "1" ); then
```

Or:

```
if TRUE( $foo ); then
```

And this is the best way of solving the problem?

EDIT: apparently this script is written in M4 http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html

Comment: If it has to run in those environments you say, I would leave the comparison as it is.

Comment: Are you looking at the `configure` script generated by autoconf?  There is generally no need for that kind of checking in configure.ac, and if you are checking strings you should be using `AS_IF` rather than raw `test`.

Answer (score 2):

For shell portability, you really should be wrapping as much as possible in [M4sh](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Common-Shell-Constructs.html#Common-Shell-Constructs) macros.  There's some special considerations for [writing portable shell code](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Portable-Shell.html#Portable-Shell) in autoconf, and that's why the code looks so arcane.

That being said, there's no restriction on cleaning up confusing code:

```
foo="1"
AS_IF([test "x$foo" = "x1"], [...])
```

[This page](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins) tells why there's leading `x` in this `test` statement.  In this case you could get away without it, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `expr` should be portable (and readable) enough:

```
if expr $foo; then
  #do something
fi
```

If you want to eliminate the output from `expr`, say: `if expr $foo >/dev/null; then`

Answer (score 1):

Using `test` requires some odd constructions to handle ancient shells.  If you don't care about those shells, you can use `AS_IF` and a straightforward test, but if you don't care about portability you probably shouldn't be bothering with autoconf.  It is probably slightly cleaner to use `AS_CASE`, IMO:

```
 AS_CASE($foo,[1], [...], [...default commands (if $foo != `)])
```